# Declaring a variable in a for loop for the array length

Tags: java, for-loop

I've recently been reviewing code an noticed the use of this syntax in a for loop

```
for(int i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++){
    //some code
}
```

as opposed to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    //some code
}
```

With the reasoning that it is more efficient as you don't have to keep looking up the myArray.length property with each loop.

I created a test to check if this was the case, and in all my tests the first for loop approach was significantly (around 70%) faster than the second.

I was curious why this syntax isn't more widely adopted and that i'm correct in thinking it is a better approach to using a for loop through an array.

Comment: "I was curious why this syntax isn't more widely adopted and that i'm correct in thinking it is a better approach to using a for loop through an array."
Because most people use iterators today :-)

Comment: IMHO the first syntax is not widely used because it is a micro optimization, if you need to squeeze out that amount of performance probably you have to rethink a lot of things, and a `for` loop might be the last.

Comment: That's a good point. Even i dislike using .size() and .length() methods in for loop. More acceptable approach would be for(String str: myarray){}

Comment: Remember that the first will come unstuck if the array length changes within the loop.

Comment: The case for reading the length once in loop initialization rather than in each iteration is stronger when the length is read from a method call (e.g. list.size()) rather than a field access (array.length).

Comment: Can we see the test  code please? Is the result [statistical significant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance)? Did you follow [proper benchmark settings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/572670)?

Comment: _"I created a test to check if this was the case, and in all my tests the first for loop approach was significantly (around 70%) faster than the second." _  Could you tell more about it?  very unlikely on normal conditions.  Did you try with JMH (http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a caching optimization, preventing, as you noted, many reads of `length`. Frequently, it's not necessary to perform this kind of micro-optimization, which may explain why most engineers are happy to examine `length` after each loop instead of caching it off, but it's useful in high-performance code. It can also be written like this, inverting the loop's direction and avoiding the use of another variable to hold the array's length:

```
for (int i = myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first approach evaluate the length only one time instead of the second where the length is evaluated each loop.

Comment: There is no computation there, only field access, which will pretty likely be optimized anyway.

Comment: I changed the word compute to evaluate but in my mind JVM will optimize this

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, most of the Java programmers go with for-each loop in case of arrays unless we want to do some manipulation with the index values

Comment: But this practice was impopular before Java 5 too.